# Generate different timing for workers for printing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a project where there are 110 workers, each work for 4 hours in a batch of 8 worker, I want to Generate timing for this workers.

e.g
   - Batch 1 
     - Worker 1-8 Timing 08:00am - 12:00pm Date 1/1/2010
   - Batch 2
     - Worker 9-16 Timing 12:00am - 04:00pm Date 1/1/2010
   - Batch 3
     - Worker 17-24 Timing 04:00am - 08:00pm Date 1/1/2010

- Batch 4

  - Worker 25-32 Timing 08:00am - 12:00pm Date **1/2/2010**

and so on, I am using ASP.NET and MS-SQL, I want to generate and save there record in database so I can print work chart for each month.

Regards Please some tips

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the issue is here, sounds pretty simple though.  I guess I'll add my 2 cents.  First, unless youre looking for perform Inserts, Updates, or Deletes for these work times, I think a database is overkill for this.. look at using XML instead.

Secondly, ASP.NET offers some pretty simple controls to display data like this.  Check out the ASP.NET Repeater Control, which allow you to create a formatted header and footer, and repeate a templated item layout.  Its pretty fast and effective, and definately in line for what youre looking for here.

Best of luck

Comment: Yes I want to update database after generating database, 8 rows at a time.